# How can I set firebase transaction in swift4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

in my app, there is a button can turn on and off, but when it is clicked from multiple users, error occer like 'true false true false false false'
it has to be in order but like false 3 times because of simultaneous input,
for it I coded up, but it doesn't work

```
func stateTransaction() {

let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Button")

        ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

            ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in

                let state = snapshot.value as! Bool

                if state == false {

                    ref.childByAutoId().setValue(true)
                    ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                        print(snapshot.value as! Bool)
                        currentData.value = state
                    })

                } else {

                    ref.childByAutoId().setValue(false)
                    ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                        print(snapshot.value as! Bool)
                        currentData.value = state
                    })
                }

                }

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)

        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

}
```

this is my code, what are problems with my code, and how can I fix it?
thanks for in advance.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to do here. At first I thought you were toggling a node either true or false on a button click. But you're creating a child node on every button click and setting it to true or false. Then the code reads that node again and assigns it to the currentData var? Why do that? You already know the state. Also telling us the code 'doesn't work' doesn't really tell us what part doesn't work. Is it throwing an error? If so, which line? Can you include a proposed Firebase structure so we know what you're expecting? (as text please, no images).

Comment: @Jay I want the value 'true' or 'false' in child(Button) is changed in order, but when there are inputs in same time, for example if there are two persons read the "false" in the child, they write 'true' simultaneously, so they have two value "true" in the child. in order to solve this problem I tried to find the solution, and I've reached 'transaction', but I don't know how to code up for transaction, those codes I wrote are just my self codes, so I am finding someone can correct it or give right one.

Comment: What I am saying is there's another query inside the first query that doesn't really do anything. If you know the previously written data was false( via the observe), then the next write will be true, so you know the `currentData.value = state` will be true in that case. [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) are covered in the documentation and the example presented could be modified for your use case. The bigger issue here is you will have no idea which user wrote false or true as it's not addressed in your code.